# update uiimageview after changing settings

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

In one of the tabs of an app I am making I have a uiimageview which is a subview of uiscrollview. I have a settings bundle with a switch to change the image of the uiimage view, and I am having trouble with the image updating after multitasking back into the app. The image will change, but when i zoom out then i can see the previous image in the background. Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL enabled = [defaults boolForKey:@"enableWinterSchedule"];

    if (enabled) {
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"WinterSchedule.png"]];
        self.imageView = tempImageView;
    } else {
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FallSpringSchedule.png"]];
        self.imageView = tempImageView;
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width , imageView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = .75;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = .37;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    scrollView.zoomScale = .37;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [imageView release];
}
```

Comment: A couple things are already wrong here:  1) don't call `[super viewDidLoad]` from your `viewDidAppear` method.  #2) I don't see you creating `imageView` in your `viewDidAppear` method, so don't release `imageView` in it there, either.

Comment: ok then, however I can still see the previous image in the background when I try zooming out right after changing the preference. Is putting it in viewdidappear the correct way to update the view after changing the preference or am I totally off on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that every time `viewDidAppear:` runs, you're adding a new imageview to the scrollview. So now you have your new image on top of your old image. `viewDidAppear:` runs every time the view is put on screen (such as when you come back to the foreground).

You meant to do this work in `viewDidLoad` (for nib file views) or `loadView` (non-nib file views).

Comment: when I have it in viewDidLoad then I have to exit out the app every time to update the view though, and then when I try opening the app again I get SIGKILL

Comment: You shouldn't get SIGKILL in any case. Are you sure you're not getting SIGSEGV? Regarding updating the view, you should modify the `image` of the `imageView` whenever the content changes. You shouldn't add a new `imageView`. You can modify the image in `viewWillAppear:`. You should likely keep an ivar pointing to the imageview to simplify this.

Comment: thank you for your help, now the image changes when I change the preference and go back into the app, and it doesn't create an image every time. Only thing is that if I leave it on the tab with the image and then I change the preference and go back into the app, I have to switch tabs first in order for it to refresh. Any tips for solving that problem? I've tried using applicationdidbecomeactive before but I didn't have much luck with that

Comment: I'm not clear on your architecture to know your specific issue, but here is some broad advice. Think carefully about when the various methods run rather than trying things until it "works." Separate data (Model) from display (View). Remember that views can be unloaded any time they're off screen, so never trust views to hold your data for you. Create views in `viewDidLoad`. Configure your views (setting the image within the imageview) in `viewWillAppear:`. Keep track of what image you need to display in a Model class (or at least in a Controller class) separate from the View.